# Oracle Dynamic SQL with optional input params separated by #

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic

OK -- so this is a little difficult to explain....

I need to send back a refcursor

The select statements need parameters which can have multiple values in each, which can also be optional.

so for example a statement like :

select * from Table A where Column1 in ('A', 'B', 'C') and column2 in ('3', '4', '5');

But the values for filters of Column1 are passed as an input parameter, like so 'A#B#C'
and the values for filters of Column2 are passed as input parameter like '3#4#5'

Also, if the input parameter is NULL, I do not want to add that filter to the where clause.

My SP is written like so

```
PROCEDURE GET_RECS (
    p_users IN VARCHAR2,
 p_clients IN VARCHAR2
, p_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)

IS
v_sql varchar2(4000);
    v_crlf char(2) := chr(13) || chr(10);

begin
v_sql := 'select A.col1, A.col2 from table1 A where 1 = 1 ' || v_crlf;
if p_users is not null then
v_sql := v_SQL || ' and a.user in (SELECT * FROM TABLE ( CAST (str2tbl (:p_users ) AS     TableType) )) ' || v_crlf;
end if;
if p_clients is not null then
v_sql := v_SQL || ' and a.client in (SELECT * FROM TABLE ( CAST (str2tbl (:p_clients ) AS TableType) )) ' || v_crlf;
 end if;

if p_users is not null then
OPEN p_cursor FOR v_sql using p_users ;
 end if;
if p_clients is not null then
OPEN p_cursor FOR v_sql using p_clients ;
 end if;

end;
```

I also know that the above code is incorrect in the "Open cursor for " block is incorrect as it does not take into consideration that neither params are sent, or that both params are sent.

The above is a sample with 2 filters, but my actual query has more filter combinations. Thus the Open Cursor for block should also be dynamic, if possible.

I have created a function called str2tbl which easily converts '3#4#5' into a table. The code for that is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function str2tbl
 (p_str   in varchar2,
  p_delim in varchar2 default '#')
 return      TableType
 as
 l_str      long default p_str || p_delim;
 l_n        number;
 l_data     TableType := TableType();
 begin
 loop
     l_n := instr( l_str, p_delim );
     exit when (nvl(l_n,0) = 0);
     l_data.extend;
     l_data( l_data.count ) := ltrim(rtrim(substr(l_str,1,l_n-1)));
     l_str := substr( l_str, l_n+length(p_delim) );
 end loop;
 return l_data;
 end;
```

Comment: What is the design justification for this approach? Sounds like a SQL statment generator. This will potentially create huge performance problems as no hints can be provided.

Comment: do you have an alternate design which I can follow to achieve this. perhaps temp tables?